# Android fails to inflate layout

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I'm working on a project and a section of it that has been working for weeks all of a sudden throws the following error

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class

My layout file looks like this.  I can't understand why it would stop working or even a direction as to how to fix it.

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_view"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_primary_image"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jenny_thumb"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="90dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text=""/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_posted"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#C1C1C1"
                android:text=""/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_headline_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_comment_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ECECEC">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The stack trace is below:

```
02-19 15:45:40.809  31057-31057/com.smartsocialmedia.connect E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.smartsocialmedia.utility.CommunitiesFragment$CommunityDirPostFragment.onCreateView(CommunitiesFragment.java:124)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.smartsocialmedia.utility.CommunitiesFragment$CommunityDirPostFragment.onCreateView(CommunitiesFragment.java:124)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.smartsocialmedia.utility.CommunitiesFragment$CommunityDirPostFragment.onCreateView(CommunitiesFragment.java:124)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is how I'm inflating it

```
            View headlineView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment_headline, container, false);
```

Comment: i don't find this element in your xml first Linearlayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: Please clarify mohammed

Comment: Are ur namespace correct, java doesnt take any capital letters in namespace, classes can have thuogh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitmaps are notorious for memory problems. As you can see by looking further down, the real problem is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
```

This looks like it's a small bitmap. I would put several bitmaps, one for each size (mdpi, hdpi, etc) in a folder, and put them in the appropriate drawable folder. Make them the exact size! In fact, I would use the standard icon sizes found in the [Android Iconography page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). For reference, here's an image that shows the standard multipliers.

[image]

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer... I was running out of memory

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView` is causing the issue, whatever the root cause is. Can you check that `"@drawable/jenny_thumb"` is properly formatted and/or whether it points to a correct bitmap? Would swapping it with another image solve the issue?

Comment: Nope... but thanks... I was just running out of memory